# Image loading taking too much time in android device?

Tags: coronasdk

In my game,i used more physics object.so its taking to much time to load images.but only in android device.In simulator its run perfectly.but i had problem in android device.please help me.After all physics object loads its run fine.but taking some time in changescene.i searched over the net but i did not get any solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think you probably delete and recreate images while change scene operation. Try to load all images before you do anything. You can simply load them into device's ram as :

```
display.newImageRect( name, xVal, yVal )
```